show/hide table rows with animation
There are plenty examples on the net for the use case, if we want to show/hide table rows f. e. with fade in/out or with slide. Most of them uses jQuery and wraps the rows/cells in a div.
In my case I have let's say 11 rows. The first row is the 'group' row with a button in it. All the other 10 rows below it are detail rows. On button click, I add or remove this css classes to/from this 10 rows:
.enhanced.k-grid .collapsed-row {
  display: none;
}

.enhanced.k-grid .expanded-row {
  display: table-row;
}

While this works, but the rows are hiding/showing instantly. The question is, how could I apply some animations to this 10 rows without using extra divs or jQuery? I extend a third party table, so I have limited options.
EDIT:
I'm well aware of the possibility to animate the display property, which I already tried, but with no luck. The speciality of this question is, that I want to animate table rows, whithout adding extra elements to the DOM. And I'm asking how to do that. I'm not asking, how to animate the display property in a general manner. Maybe the direction with the display property is totally wrong.
